# Как корректно передать результат работы метода в другой метод?

Tags: javascript

Как корректно передать результат методов `countAmountOfClasses` и `countAmountOfVisits` в переменную `averageVisit` которая находиться в методе `summary`.
На данный момент `averageVisit` выдает `NaN`.

```js
class Student {
    constructor(firstName,lastName,yearOfBirth,arrayOfGrades) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.arrayOfGrades = arrayOfGrades;
    }
    //______Возраст студента______//
    getAge () {
        return console.log(`${this.firstName}'s old is ${2023 - this.yearOfBirth} years`);
    }
    //______Средний бал______//
    averageMark () {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayOfGrades.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + this.arrayOfGrades[i];
        }
        return console.log(`${this.firstName}'s average mark is ${sum / this.arrayOfGrades.length}`);
    }

}
//______Экземпляры студентов______//
const student = new Student('Dmitriy','Yaroshchuk',2001,[70,80,90,100,90,90,99,100,95,100]);
const student1 = new Student('Andrew','Kavetsky',2000,[90,90,90,90,90,90,100,100,95,93]);
const student2 = new Student('Diana','Koko',1999,[70,70,70,70,70,70,75,75,75,93]);



//______Вызываю методы______//
student.getAge();
student1.getAge();
student2.getAge();
student.averageMark();
student1.averageMark();
student2.averageMark();

class Visit extends Student {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
        this.visitinMagazine = [];
    }
    //______Используется когда студент был на занятие______//
    present () {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 26) {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(true);
            return this;
        } else {
            return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        }
    }
    //______Используется когда студент НЕ был на занятие______//
    absent () {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 26) {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
            return this;
        } else {
            return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        }
    }
}

//______Экземпляры посейщения______//
const visit = new Visit('Dmitriy', 'Yaroshchuk', 2001, [70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 90, 99, 100, 95, 100])
const visit1 = new Visit('Andrew', 'Kavetsky', 2000, [90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 95, 93])
const visit2 = new Visit('Diana', 'Koko', 1999, [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 93])

//______Посейщение уроков______//
visit.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent();
// const callOfVisitnMagazine = [...visit.visitinMagazine];

//______Посейщение уроков______//
visit1.absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().present().present();
// const callOfVisitnMagazine1 = [...visit1.visitinMagazine];

//______Посейщение уроков______//
visit2.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent();
// const callOfVisitnMagazine2 = [...(visit2.visitinMagazine)];


 class Calculation extends Visit {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
    }
     //______Колличество занятий______//
     countAmountOfClasses () {
         return console.log(this.arrayOfGrades.length);
     }
     //______Колличество посищений______//
     countAmountOfVisits (visitinMagazine) {
        return console.log(visitinMagazine.filter((element) => element === true).length);
     }
     //______Проверяем среднюю оценку и посейщение______//
     summary () {
         const averageVisit = this.countAmountOfVisits / this.countAmountOfClasses;
         if (this.averageMark > 90 && averageVisit > 0.9) {
             return console.log('Cool!');
         } else if (this.averageMark > 90 || averageVisit > 0.9) {
             return console.log('Good, but it can be better!');
         } else {
             return console.log('Radish');
         }
     }
 }
//______Экземпляры расчетов______//
const calculate = new Calculation('Dmitriy', 'Yaroshchuk', 2001, [70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 90, 99, 100, 95, 100]);
const calculate1 = new Calculation('Andrew', 'Kavetsky', 2000, [90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 95, 93]);
const calculate2 = new Calculation('Diana', 'Koko', 1999, [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 93]);

calculate.countAmountOfClasses();
calculate1.countAmountOfClasses();
calculate2.countAmountOfClasses();

calculate.countAmountOfVisits(visit.visitinMagazine);
calculate1.countAmountOfVisits(visit1.visitinMagazine);
calculate2.countAmountOfVisits(visit2.visitinMagazine);

calculate.summary();
calculate1.summary();
calculate2.summary();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного заблудились в классах...
Каждый экземпляр класса сущестувет обособленно.

Вам надо создавать экземпляр из класса Calculation и уже дальше вызывать все необходимые методы

```js
class Student {
  constructor(firstName,lastName,yearOfBirth,arrayOfGrades) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    this.arrayOfGrades = arrayOfGrades;
    this.age = new Date().getFullYear() - this.yearOfBirth;
    this.avgMark = arrayOfGrades.reduce((acc, it) => acc += it, 0)/arrayOfGrades.length;
  }
  //______Возраст студента______//
  getAge () {
    return `${this.firstName}'s old is ${this.age} years`
  }
  //______Средний бал______//
  averageMark () {
    return `${this.firstName}'s average mark is ${this.avgMark}`;
  }
}

class Visit extends Student {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
    super(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
    this.visitinMagazine = [];
  }
  //______Используется когда студент был на занятие______//
  present () {
    this.visitinMagazine.length < 26 ? this.visitinMagazine.push(true) : this.visitinMagazine.pop();
    return this;
  }
  //______Используется когда студент НЕ был на занятие______//
  absent () {
    this.visitinMagazine.length < 26 ? this.visitinMagazine.push(false) : this.visitinMagazine.pop();
    return this
  }
}

class Calculation extends Visit {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
    super(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
  }
  //______Проверяем среднюю оценку и посейщение______//
  summary () {
    const averageVisit = this.arrayOfGrades.length / this.visitinMagazine.filter(el => !!el).length
    if (this.avgMark > 90 && averageVisit > 0.9) {
      return `${this.firstName} Cool!`;
    } else if (this.avgMark > 90 || averageVisit > 0.9) {
      return `${this.firstName} Good, but it can be better!`;
    } else {
      return `${this.firstName} Radish`;
    }
  }
}
//______Экземпляры расчетов______//
const calculate = new Calculation('Dmitriy', 'Yaroshchuk', 2001, [70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 90, 99, 100, 95, 100]);
const calculate1 = new Calculation('Andrew', 'Kavetsky', 2000, [90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 95, 93]);
const calculate2 = new Calculation('Diana', 'Koko', 1999, [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 93]);

// Общая информация
console.log(calculate.getAge());
console.log(calculate1.getAge());
console.log(calculate2.getAge());

console.log(calculate.averageMark());
console.log(calculate1.averageMark());
console.log(calculate2.averageMark());

//______Посейщение уроков______//
calculate.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent();
calculate1.absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().present().present();
calculate2.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent();


console.log(calculate.summary());
console.log(calculate1.summary());
console.log(calculate2.summary());
```

Comment: скажите могу ли я рассчитать возраст студента и средний бал именно в методах `getAge` и `averageMark` ?